# Как получить свойства объекта из DocumentSnapshot firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firestore

В сервисе получаю documentSnapshot документа из firebase.

```
  getBelbinById(id: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('belbin').doc(id).get();
  }
```

В компоненте подписываюсь на этот сервис и получаю этот documentSnapshot по подписке:

```
this.sub = this.belbinService.getBelbinById(this.personId)
.subscribe((documentSnapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
  console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
}
```

На этом у меня начинаются проблемы, так как не могу ничего сделать с data() - нет доступа к свойствам объекта...
Сам объект имеет вид и нормально выводится в консоль ([image: смотрите скрин])

```
{ id: "ya1jibU2pZx1niGiuAmp"
  qwCF: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 2]
  qwCO: [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
  qwIMP: [10, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0]
  qwME: [0, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0]
  qwPL: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  qwRI: [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
  qwSH: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  qwTW: [0, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 8] }
```

Сломал голову, почему не могу получить доступ к свойствам data(), подскажите в чем проблема?
Доступ пробую получить так:

```
this.sub = this.belbinService.getBelbinById(this.personId)
.subscribe((documentSnapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
  this.id = documentSnapshot.data().id;
  this.qwCF = documentSnapshot.data().qwCF;
}
```

Comment: У вас где-то правила должны [настраиваться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269947/angular-firebase-permission-error-to-access-data)

Comment: У меня правила настроены. Я получаю объект из базы, даже скрин показал. Но почему-то не могу прочитать свойства этого объекта, что-то с форматами видимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказали в англоязычной ветке. Оказывается, нужно было сначала из documentSnapshot создать переменную. Уже после этого получать доступ к ее свойствам. Не понимаю, почему нужна эта итерация, но это работает.

```
this.sub = this.belbinService.getBelbinById(this.personId)
.subscribe((documentSnapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
  const data = documentSnapshot.data();
  this.qwCF = data.qwCF;
}
```